# Xpath - How to get all the attribute names and values of an element

Tags: java, xpath, attributes, element

I am using xpath in java. I want to get all the attributes (name & Value) of an element. I found the query to get the attribute values of an element, now I want to get attribute names alone or names and values in single query.

```
<Element1 ID="a123" attr1="value1" attr2="value2" attr3="value3" attr4="value4" attr5="value5" />
```

Here using the following query to get all the attribute values of `Element1`
`XmlUtils.getAttributes(Path, String.format("//*/@*"));`
Using this format `//*/@*` I can get the values. result would be `value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 a123`

Now I want to know the query to get all the attribute names, or query to get all the attributes name and value.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To select all attributes of all elements in the document named Element1: `//Element1/@*`. This will return a *nodeset* containing *attribute* nodes. You can then iterate the nodeset.

If you already have a context node and wish to find results under it, the query would be `.//Element1/@*`. This is usually more efficient than querying the entire document.

```
// input is an InputSource or a DOM node
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Element1/@*", input, XPathConstants.NODESET);
int length = nl.getLength();
for( int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    Attr attr = (Attr) nl.item(i);
    String name = attr.getName();
    String value = attr.getValue();
}
```

And it may be more efficient to find all elements of a given name using [getElementsByTagName](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29).

```
NodeList nl = document.getElementsByTagName("Element1");
```

To get the attributes of a particular element, iterate its *attributes* property.

```
NamedNodeMap nl = element.getAttributes();
int length = nl.getLength();
for( int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    Attr attr = (Attr) nl.item(i);
    String name = attr.getName();
    String value = attr.getValue();
}
```

Comment: great ans! i was looking exactly for this! Thanks! (Btw... there's a typo, it's String, not string)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it in Oracle Service Bus and had to do using only xPath to create a cache key and the solution that work for me was:

```
concat(
    string-join(//*[string-length(normalize-space(string-join(text(), ''))) > 0]/concat(local-name(), 
                                                                                        ':',
                                                                                        normalize-space(string-join(text(), ''))), '_'), 
    '_',
    string-join(//@*[normalize-space(.) != '']/concat(name(), ':', .), '_')
)
```